# highcharts - render text with decimal 'x' and 'y'

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to render text using [svgRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text) and noticed that I can't set x and y to decimal.
Am I missing something?
Here's an example - https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/dxhz9qn8/1/

```
chart.renderer.text('Series 1', 140.5, 140)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values `x` and `y` are rounded in the `text` renderer method: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/5e3927f5d3922c72c40d64a028dbc8a2e81bb34e/js/Core/Renderer/SVG/SVGRenderer.js#L1746

```
attribs.y = Math.round(y);
```

That operation is probably for text anti-aliasing. To prevent such behavior you can overwrite the `text` method: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/exvmq8p1/

---

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts